# Where is the STDOUT buffer?

Tags: c, linux

As we know, STDOUT is buffered in Linux. My question is: 1) is it a global buffer shared by all processes? or one buffer for each process? 2) where the buffer is? on stack, or heap or static area? 3) who creates it?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: My understanding is that it is created by the kernel within a kernel heap area, and is then accessible through /dev/stdout.

Answer (score 3):

`stdout` is a C `FILE` pointer created by the standard library, so the relevant code is loaded as part of your C library. On Linux, it will be implemented in terms of Posix file descriptors.

Both your C library and the kernel may use buffering; you'll have to check the individual documentations. I recommend to start by looking at the relevant part of the source code of the C library (i.e. the part that implements `<stdio.h>`), which should be very educational.

Answer (score 3):

Best resource to learn about the C standard library in excruciating detail is P. J. Plauger's [*The Standard C Library*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099). He describes all the issues that arose while he implemented the library by himself (in MSWord! on a win3.1 laptop! on vacation!).

He also gives detailed information on how to use (and test) every function.

For the Unix (Linux) side, you should start reading about 'inode's, which is the classic data structure for storing in-memory cached files. The classic book for this is [*The Design of the UNIX Operating System*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) by Maurice J. Bach.

---

Alright, now that you're suitably scolded for not having read all the old books and every related wiki page.

Here's a relevant quote from *The Standard C Library*, p. 256.

> You can, in principle, exercise a certain amount of control over how the I/O functions buffer data for a stream. You must realize, however, that buffering is an optimization based on various conjectures about patterns of I/O. These conjectures are usually correct, and many implementations follow your advice. But they don't have to. An implementation is free to ignore most of your buffering requests.
>
> Nevertheless, if you think a bigger buffer will improve performance or a smaller buffer will save space, you can supply your own candidate buffer. Call the function `setvbuf` after you open the file, and before you perform any other operations on the stream. (Avoid the older function `setbuf`, which is less flexible.) You can specify whether I/O should be fully buffered, buffered by text lines, or unbuffered. It just might make a difference in how well your program performs.
>
> ...
>
> `setbuf` -- Use `setvbuf` instead of this function to get more control.
>
> `setvbuf` -- As a rule, it is best to let the Standard C library decide how to buffer input/output for you. If you are certain that you want no buffering or line-at-a-time buffering, the use this function to initialize the stream properly. Call `setvbuf` *immediately* after you open the stream. Almost any operation on the stream will preempt your right to choose a buffering strategy. Should you specify your own buffer with this call, don't assume that the stream will actually use it. And *never* alter the contents of the buffer while the stream is open. The **mode** (third) argument must have one of the values `_IOFBF`, `_IOLBF`, or `_IONBF`, described above. Also see the macro `BUFSIZ`, described [elsewhere].
>
> ...

```
/* setbuf function */
#include "xstdio.h"

int (setbuf)(FILE *str, char *buf)
    {        /* set up buffer for a stream */
    setvbuf(str, buf, buf ? _IOFBF : _IONBF, BUFSIZ);
    }

/* setvbuf function */
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "xstdio.h"

int (setvbuf)(FILE *str, char *abuf, int smode, size_t size)
    {         /* set up buffer for a stream */
    int mode;
    unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char *)abuf;

    if (str->_Mode & (_MREAD|_MWRITE))
        return (-1);
    mode = smode == _IOFBF ? 0
        : smode == _IOLBF ? _MLBF
        : smode == _IONBF ? _MNBF : -1;
    if (mode == -1)
        return (-1);
    if (size == 0)
        buf = &str->_Cbuf, size = 1;
    else if (INT_MAX < size)
        size = INT_MAX;
    if (buf)
        ;
    else if ((buf = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        return (-1);
    else
        mode |= _MALBUF;
    if (str->_Mode & _MALBUF)
        free(str->_Buf), str->_Mode &= ~_MALBUF;
    str->_Mode |= mode;
    str->_Buf = buf;
    str->_Bend = buf + size;
    str->_Next = buf;
    str->_Rend = buf;
    str->_Wend = buf;
    return (0);
    }
```

So, at least in this implementation, the default buffer probably lives in the FILE structure and is allocated on the heap. We can see here its brother, a character buffer (`str->_CBuf`), is used for "unbuffered".

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you write to stdout. If you use `stdio`, it will be line buffered, if the output goes to a tty. Otherwise it will be fully buffered.

See also [`man stdio`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/stdio.3.html) for more details.

If you use low level routines like [`write`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html), only the given bytes are written. Depending on the target, there will be buffering in the kernel. If the target is a tty, it might be written to the terminal directly.