# Where is the screen buffer for the windows console?

Tags: windows, console

In Windows, I know I can redirect console output to a file thusly:
command > file

But what happens if I want to save the output of my stdout AFTER the fact.? In my case, the width of the console is 160 and many of the lines of output go beyond the bounds of the console (so I can't select them with the mouse)

Is there a way to access the the screen buffer somewhere? Is there a temp file somewhere on the disk? ( In linux it seems it's in RAM only as discussed here
[Where is the STDOUT buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933629/where-is-the-stdout-buffer))

Is there another way to save only some of the stdoutput to a file ? 
(I know I can right click and select all, paste that into a document and then edit that. I was looking for a solution that would allow me to directly select a block of text that has 'run off the screen' and repaste that into a doc)

The reason I do not want to do the command over again is that the output is very long.
C:\Users\me >symchk /r c:\windows\system32 /s SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

This caches the debug symbol table for all the code in the sys32 folder.

Comment: It is unspecified.  Use GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo() to discover geometry, and, say, ReadConsoleOutputCharacter() to read text from the buffer.  It won't be "long", the buffer cannot be larger than 64KB.  This can only be done in-process, you need to use redirection if it is not your program.

Comment: The screen buffer itself can exceed 64KB. I usually use 120x5000. Prior to Windows 8, the buffer used for reading/writing has to be (much) less than 64K. Communicating large messages between the client and server (conhost.exe) via LPC uses a fixed-size heap of shared memory, so you have to slide a window.  Windows 8+ doesn't have this limit because the console uses a device driver, i.e. Windows can call `NtDeviceIoControlFile`, `NtReadFile` and `NtWriteFile` instead of using LPC ports and shared memory.

Comment: thank you for your comments. But i do not not have access to a debugging environment where I can enter statements like:ReadConsoleOutputCharacter()  and have them execute on a running console process. I guess I just have to copy everything (right click in console->select all, right click again, then switch to notepad and paste)

Comment: Can't you create a GUI that calls `AttachConsole` and then proceeds as the first comment suggests?